# Text not lined up properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I *thought* was OK, but apparently some people have issues with the text, and because of that I may have shot myself in the foot when it comes to showing off my portfolio to employers.  The major problem is I'm not seeing what other people are seeing.  Or, maybe they *are* seeing what I'm seeing, but it's just not designed well.

First of all, I would like you to check my website: http://mmking9999.com

After browsing around for a bit, please have a look at my code and tell me where I went wrong.  If you have any other suggestions, let me know.  Here's the code for the main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" href="http://mmking9999.com/css/style.css" />

</head>
<body>

<!--Site logo. Clicking on it will redirect to this page.-->
<div class="logo">
<a href="http://mmking9999.com/"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/SiteLogo.png" /></a>
</div>

<!-- Menu window goes here. The text are images that link to other pages.-->

<div class="menu">
<img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/MenuWindow.png" />
</div>


<div class="portfolio_url">
<a href="http://mmking9999.com/portfoliopage.html"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/portfoliourl.png"  /></a>
</div>

<div class="blog_url">
<img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/blogurl.png"  />
</div>

<div class="random_url">
<a href="http://mmking9999.com/randomstuff.html"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/randomurl.png"  /></a>
</div>

<div class="email">
<a href="mailto:mmking9999@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/emailicon.png"  /></a>
</div>

<div class="linkedin">
<a href="http://ca.linkedin.com/in/mikeadmurray" target="_blank"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/linkedinicon.png"  /></a>
</div>

<div class="twitter">
<a href="http://twitter.com/MikeADMurray" target="_blank"><img src="http://mmking9999.com/Images/twittericon.png"  /></a>
</div>


<div class="window"><br><br><p>Welcome to my website!  My name is Mike Murray, a rookie game developer/designer. Here, you'll find stuff about what I do and what I hope to become in the future.  I am an avid gamer, and it was that passion that led me to want to create the video games that people like to play.  Having played video games for over 20 years, I figure I should be able to create something cool with the knowledge I have!</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS I'm using:

```
/*The code for the body sets the default settings for all pages */
body 
{
    background-image:url('http://mmking9999.com/Images/sitewallpaper.png');
}

/* Link colours. I use bright colours to contrast the black window. */
a:link {
COLOR: #86C6FE;
}
a:visited {
COLOR: #FF0000;
}
a:hover {
COLOR: #FFFF00;
}
a:active {
COLOR: #00FF00;
}

/* Main window. Used to display text and images */
img
{
    margin: 2px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

h1
{
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:calibri;
}

p
{
    /* font */
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-family:"Small Fonts", calibri, arial, "Times New Roman";
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:left; width:700px; margin-left:200px;
}

/* Main window. All info is displayed in here */
div.window
{
    background-image:url('http://mmking9999.com/Images/IframeWindow.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
    height:70%;
    top:80px;
    left:500px;

    /*text*/
    /*color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-family:"Small Fonts", calibri, arial, "Times New Roman";
    font-size:18px;*/

}

/* Menu */
div.menu
{
    position:relative;
    width:40%;
    height:10%;
}

/*Site logo */
div.logo
{
    position:relative;
    width:40%;
    height:5%;
    left:500px;
}

/*Images (so they aren't constrained by the attributes defined in div.window)*/
div.image
{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
}

/* In case I need another row of images */
div.image2
{
    position:relative;
    left:-150px;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
}

/*Menu urls*/
div.portfolio_url
{
    position:relative;
    left:-175px;
    top:30px;
}

div.blog_url
{
    position:relative;
    left:-305px;
    top:90px;
}

div.random_url
{
    position:relative;
    left:-445px;
    top:150px;
}

div.email
{
    position:relative;
    top:250px;
    left:-600px;
}

div.linkedin
{
    position:relative;
    top:250px;
    left:-580px;
}

div.twitter
{
    position:relative;
    top:250px;
    left:-560px;
}

/*iframe
{

    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    left:280px;
    width:60%; height:70%;
}*/
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://d.pr/i/OhIF

Try using position:absolute rather than relative on your divs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that and see if it'll help.  Not looking forward to re-positioning stuff manually, haha.

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome's inspect element when you right click? It makes things much easier. Also, Firebug works wonders.

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm using Chrome to edit the page.  I'll check out Firebug, looks cool.

Comment: How does the page look now?  The whole reason I went with relative positions was to account for people who don't maximize their screens, but I guess it didn't work out like I wanted.